# Uniform continuity proof problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb R$ and assume that there is a constant $C$ such that

$$|f(x)| \leq C$$

for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Let $g$ be uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.  Show that $fg$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$.

I just need a hint on how to start this! I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Start with the definition of uniform continuity!

Comment: Hint: It's wrong. $f$ needs to be uniformly continuous too. And even that isn't sufficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer, we are now given that |g(x)| is less than or equal to a constant M. Does this make it solvable?

Comment: You still need the uniform continuity of $f$. Consider $f(x) = \sin (x^2)$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true: you need more. In particular, let us understand what is missing. 
$fg$ is uniformly continuous on whole $\mathbb R$ if

$$\forall \epsilon>0 ~\text{there exists} ~\delta=\delta(\epsilon)~ \text{s.t.}~
\forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb R : |x_1-x_2|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x_1)g(x_1)-f(x_2)g(x_2)|<\epsilon~~(*)$$

Let us study conditions on $f$ and $g$ to ensure $(*)$. We can write

$$|f(x_1)g(x_1)-f(x_2)g(x_2)|=|f(x_1)g(x_1)+f(x_1)g(x_2) - f(x_1)g(x_2) -f(x_2)g(x_2)|\leq |f(x_1)g(x_1)-f(x_1)g(x_2)  |+
|f(x_1)g(x_2)-f(x_2)g(x_2)|=\\|f(x_1)||g(x_1)-g(x_2)|+ 
|g(x_2)||f(x_1)-f(x_2)|; $$

Now, in the first term in the r.h.s. of the last equality, i.e. $|f(x_1)||g(x_1)-g(x_2)|$ we can use that $f$ is bounded and $g$ is uniformly continuous. What about the second term, i.e.
$$|g(x_2)||f(x_1)-f(x_2)| ~~(**)$$

? Can you find additional hypothesis on $f$ and $g$ to estimate $(**)$ and arrive at the thesis, i.e. $(*)$?

Comment: Okay. That makes sense to me. So there's absolutely no way to estimate (**)? |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| would be less than 2C, right? but I guess we can't estimate |g(x_2)|?

Comment: if $f$ is also uniformly continuous and $g$ is bounded, then...ps: btw, do you see in $(*)$ where "uniformly" lies?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: what is the difference between "continuity" and "uniform continuity"? It is a small detail in $(*)$, i.e. the fact that $\delta$ is a function only of $\epsilon$, and not of points $x\in\mathbb R$. This is an important fact, that makes uniform continuity on a set stronger than continuity

Comment: @Avitus: I gave the start for the OP to work his problem out and see what conditions he needs to impose on the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start,

$$ |g(x)f(x)-g(y)f(y)| = |g(x)f(x)-g(y)f(x)+g(y)f(x)-g(y)f(y)|  $$

$$  \leq |g(x)f(x)-g(y)f(x)| + |g(y)f(x)-g(y)f(y)| . $$

Comment: What's the downvote for? This is a start for OP to work his problem out and see what kind of conditions he needs to impose on his function. Instead, @Avitus did the job.